# How to access an element that's a child of owned component and doesn't have a ref="..." attribute

Tags: reactjs

Example:

```
var Top = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <A>
        <B>child</B>
      </A>
    );
  }
});
```

Is there a way to access all `Top`'s child components that don't have a `ref` attribute (e.g. `B`) and loop over them?

Comment: You should be able to access the DOM from `componentDidMount`. Although, it's not clear why you would do that. What problem are you trying to solve? Why can't you use a `ref`?

Comment: I'm writing an utility function that should traverse children and refs and collect their state into a tree. Whether a state should be saved or not for a particular child/owned component is regulated by its special prop. Which fields to save is regulated by its method. So, I need to loop over React elements, not over DOM elements, actually. For now the workaround is to add ref="..." to those elements that I want to traverse and serialize, but that's redundant code as I those refs are only used to traverse. P.S. This reflects GraphQL, but much simpler.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this for different reasons.  I'm planning to make a react component that lays out its children in grid blocks that the user can drag to a different position and resize.  In some cases it would be nice for the layout element to be able to call an `onResize()` handler on the child elements.  But since the children are passed in it can't add ref tags to them.

Comment: You can always build values for refs dynamically, no? ref_1, ref_2 etc.